# my app dosen't show in google play on bellow android 9

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

i released my app  few months ago , but sum off client can't install the app,

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vakiltop.app

my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.vakiltop.app'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 8
        versionName '8.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
}
```

**minSdk : 21** but the app in unavailable ,

> can any one help

Comment: Have you tried digging the settings in Google Play Console already?

Comment: @SujalKumar how can change settings for android version in console